# Android Paint. 2 canvas?

Tags: android, paint, android-canvas

I let my user draw geometries on it. So I store all the data(ie. coordinates) required for each geometries(ie. line, triangle, quads, etc). Now, I'm implementing a paint/brush on it which I don't care about all the points that was inputted. My problem is I need to call canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE); every time the user modify the geometry resulting to clearing also the paint which is gone now and I don't have access to.

Is there any way to actually separate the two in two canvas and combining it later? I mean, the paint is directly draw on one canvas and the geometry on other canvas and combine it.

Answer (score 0):

Yout can set the backgroundcolor of your View to White.

```
mView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
```

This way you dont need to use

```
canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Check out TouchPaint.java in the API demos included in the Android SDK, for an example of how you can do what you want to do.